# What are the gameplay implications for each of the Digital Deluxe items?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am looking at buying Guild Wars 2, and I was wondering what the in-game implications of each of the items available with the Digital Deluxe/Collections Edition have?

The items in question are:

- Summon Mistfire Wolf Elite Skill
- Miniature Rytlock
- Golem Banker
- Chalice of Glory
- Tome of Influence

The reason I ask is because generally the items included with such editions don't have an advantageous effect on game play (for example with World of Warcraft you get vanity pets) but there are instances in other games where this is not the case (for example The Secret World, where you got a pet cat which increased experience gain during the initial part of the story).

It is worth noting that I have not played Guild Wars or Guild Wars 2 previously, so I'm not aware of what the various pieces of in-game terminology refer to or effect, for example the tooltip text for 'Tome of Influence' on the Guild Wars 2 site states 'Give your guild a one-time boost of Influence' - but I do not know what effect this actually *has*.

What are the gameplay implications for each of the Digital Deluxe items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't really speak for the [elite skill](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Summon_Mistfire_Wolf)'s power. I assume though that it is on par with the other summon skills. It doesn't give an advantage to people with it, just another choice of elite skill. It's not necessarily a better one.

The [miniature Rytlock](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miniature_Rytlock) is a cosmetic item: it will make a miniature character run after you. The miniature doesn't fight, and can't help you in any way.

The [Golem Banker](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Golem_Banker) is a convenience item, allowing you a fast access to your bank, from almost any place in the game world. It's a consumable, usable only once. Once used, it lasts 5 days.

The [Chalice of Glory](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Chalice_of_Glory) is a one-time-use item giving 5000 of [glory](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glory) to your account. This allows you to buy cosmetic upgrades for your PvP weapons.

The [Tome of Influence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tome_of_influence) is also a one-time-use item which gives 1000 of [Influence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Influence) to the Guild you currently represent. Influence allows the guild to do research, and unlock guild services. Note that an equivalent to the tome of influence is earned through the game, the [Letter of Commendation](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Letter_of_Commendation).

---

All in all, it doesn't really give a gameplay advantage over people with the normal edition. You just get items which are mostly convenient, or cosmetic.

Comment: @pixel - I made a mistake, actually, editing now. You can't get these items through the story. You can get an equivalent of the Tome of Influence, though.

Comment: To be frank, the elite skill basically means you have a "free" elite skill once you unlock it at level 30, instead of having to spend skill points to buy another one. That said, at level 30, it's not particularly strong...

Comment: It's worth noting that the Golem Banker is a once per character item, not a once per account one like the others, so you get your five days on each character you create.

Comment: I'll also note that after about an hour and a half of sPvP, I received around 1000 glory.

That same bout, done together with a guildmate, brought in around 350-400 influence, if I recall.

All in all, the effect isn't very significant, but it is noticeable, especially coming from just one player.

Answer (score 1):

Gnoupi's answer covered the items pretty well, so I'll talk a bit about the elite skill, Summon Mistfire Wolf.

Compared to other elites, Summon Mistfire Wolf is actually *weaker*. The closest analogue would be the Human elite Hounds of Balthazar. The Mistfire Wolf is *slightly* stronger than a single Hound of Balthazar, but the Hounds elite summons 2, plus the Hounds have a PBAoE attack.

The reason Summon Mistfire Wolf is weaker (in addition to the fact that it's a promo ability) is that unlike all the other elite skills, it unlocks automatically as soon as you reach level 30 and can use elites. The other elites have to be purchased for 10 or 30 skill points before they can be used.