# Guild Wars 2 Digital Deluxe items acquisition

Tags: guild-wars-2

A few months ago, I've purchased the pre-order edition of Guild Wars 2 Digital Deluxe. I haven't been able to play the game up untill now due a computer upgrade. I was wondering which items can be used on every character, and which items can only be used once on your account. This because I'd like to make sure my correct character gets the items.

Next to that, how do you get the items ingame?

Here is a list of items, is this complete?

> **Summon Mistfire Wolf Elite Skill** 
>   This unique elite skill allows the
>   player to summon a temporary Mistfire Wolf pet for use in combat.
>
> **Rytlock Miniature** This rare miniature is a perfect replica of Rytlock
>   Brimstone and will accompany your character on all of their adventures
>   throughout Tyria.
>
> **Golem Banker** Your very own Golem banker, at your command for 5 days!
>   This mechanical man-servant will grant you access to your account
>   storage from anywhere in the world.
>
> **Chalice of Glory** Earn some extra Glory with this one-time use chalice.
>   Use Glory to unlock rewards in PvP as well as compare your progress
>   against other players.
>
> **Tome of Influence** Give your guild a one-time boost of influence.
>   Useful for unlocking guild vaults, emblems and other items for your
>   guild.

Comment: Maybe. The other post was certainly helpful. Maybe I can retype this question into `How to get these items in-game?` and/or `Are these accountbound or characterbound?` ?

Comment: I still think that the duplicate question covers *most* of the ground here. I'm not sure if I prefer this question being edited or the [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/94144/1721) being expanded slightly to cover the ground here ... I suppose no choice is actually a problem. Gonna sit on the fence for this one until I see a very convincing edit.

Comment: @SadlyNot "*Gonna sit on the fence for this one...*" If that's the case, [you should have chosen 'Skip' instead of 'Leave Closed'](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/33963). That is because of reasons mentioned in this meta post: [Is there a difference between leave open/leave closed and skip?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7110/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja Thanks I'll know that for next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mistfire Wolf skill is account bound and will be available to all your characters. The chalice and tome are single one time uses, for just one of your characters.

I'm not sure on the Rytlock miniature as I don't have one.
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miniature_Rytlock
As my Hall of Monument miniatures are account based, I assume that your Rytlock will be also, but this is an educated guess.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know how to get them? Is it like /bonus or something I type in chat? I'm installing the game this evening so I was wondering where to start with!

Comment: You will get an ingame mail almost immediatly with the items attached to it.

Comment: The miniature Rytlock is account-bound so you can attach him to any character at any time (provided you don't keep auto depositing all your collectibles, because miniatures are categorized as such :P)

Comment: Note that the Summon Mistfire Wolf elite won't be available to you until you can actually equip elite skills, at level 30. It's slightly weaker than every other elite skill, but that's partly because it's unlocked automatically for you, while the other elites have to be unlocked with skill points.

Comment: It's more that Mistfire Wolf is meant to scale with level, so at level 30, it doesn't do a lot?

Comment: The Golem banker is also given to every new character as part of that mail. I think the only other item you get for subsequent characters is a teleport token to some special instance or something.

Comment: @Topperfalkon Yes, it's the portal stone to take you to the Hall of Monuments so you can collect your Legacy Items.
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Hall_of_Monuments_Portal_Stone